# Web interface for SQL Server database

Tags: database, architecture

I have been working on VB6 database desktop programming, but now a client is asking for a 
simple web interface (some inserts into SQL Server db used by a desktop application).

The question is: Which approach is better?

1)creating asp.net project, connected directly to the SQL Server database;

2)creating separate (simple) mysql database managed by php and synchronization (in 15 minutes for example)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd prefer the separate database approach.

- It's more secure.
- PHP/Mysql hosting is widespread

Answer (score 1):

Personally since you already have the SQL Server database, I see no reason whatsoever to add the complexity of another database and then synchonization. The first alternative is simpler to create and can be secure if you design it correctly.   The issue about hosting is irrelevant since you are going to your own database that already exists, so is the issue about cost since the databse is already there. Further since you are already supporting SQL Server, you may be able to reuse some code rather than write new code (mysql's version of SQL is not the same as SQl Server's version). Synching the two databases may be more complex than you think (differnt data types, etc.) and the data in the real database is not real-time whereas with the first alternative it is.

Answer (score 0):

You can pretty much achieve anything with the technologies available, it just depends on your skill and productivity with specific technologies and the availability of online help.  Plus Microsoft stuff you tend to have to pay for whereas PHP/MySQL is totally free.